# Why TextViews running into each other in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with two Textviews on the same height in a RelativeLayout running into each other.

I use the following Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/logo" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/name"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="NameNameNameNameNameNameName"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
       android:gravity="clip_horizontal" 
       android:lines="1" />

<TextView 
      android:id="@+id/information"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Distance"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/nrcoupons"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Number"
      android:layout_alignRight="@id/information"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logo" />

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/subcategory"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:text="Subcategory"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/name"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives me this view:

[alt text http://janusz.de/~janusz/view.png](http://janusz.de/~janusz/view.png)

Everything is as I need it except the two textviews name and information are displayed on the same screen space with the one on top of the other.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `@+id/name` `TextView`, add `android:layout_toLeftOf="..."` for whatever `TextView` is on the right. The screenshot and the XML do not seem to line up (screenshot appears to have "Distance" in the overwritten TextView, but the XML does not), so I'm not completely certain which widget this is.

If you are targeting Android 1.5, you will need to order the widgets in the XML such that the widgets are defined before they are referenced from `android:layout_toLeftOf` or `android:layout_toRightOf`. If you are targeting Android 1.6 and newer only, you can have them be in any order, but the first occurrence of any distinct ID must have the `+` sign, even if that first occurrence is in an `android:layout_toLeftOf` attribute instead of an `android:id` attribute.

Comment: Thank you that resolved my problem. You are right I changed the code after taking the screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Your namenamename textview is set with width = fill_parent so you can't put anything to its right ;)

Comment: changing this to wrap_content does not change anything. And there is something put to its right and is displayed as you can see in the image. Sadly it is displayed beyond the other view